# I would like bigger parentheses in \pmod

Tags: math-mode, spacing

I would like to say a congruence holds modulo a fairly large expression, `THING`, to be enclosed parenthetically.

```
\left( \mod{THING}\right)
```

seems to result in a large space between the open paren and the "mod," and

```
\pmod{THING}
```

produces parentheses too small for my taste. Is there an option less hacky than just using an `\mbox`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the `amsmath` definition seems better; I'll also use `mathtools` for the growing parentheses.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

% Here's how amsmath defines \pmod
% \newcommand{\pod}[1]{\allowbreak
%   \if@display\mkern18mu\else\mkern8mu\fi(#1)}
% \renewcommand{\pmod}[1]{\pod{{\operator@font mod}\mkern6mu#1}}

\makeatletter
\DeclarePairedDelimiterX{\pmodx}[1]{(}{)}{{\operator@font mod}\mkern6mu#1}
\renewcommand{\pmod}{%
  \allowbreak
  \if@display\mkern18mu\else\mkern8mu\fi
  \pmodx
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
a &\equiv b \pmod{n}\\
a &\equiv b \pmod[\big]{n}\\
a &\equiv b \pmod[\Big]{\frac{n}{2}}\\
a &\equiv b \pmod[\bigg]{\sum_{k=1}^n k^2}\\
a &\equiv b \pmod*{\sqrt{\sum_{k=1}^n k^3}\,}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

It would be easy to define also `\pod` with the same idea.

[image]

It's not a good idea to use `\mod`, which is defined to be like `\pmod` but without parentheses.

Answer (score 5):

The commands `\mod` and `pmod` are intended to be used like

```
 x\equiv y\pmod b \qquad x\equiv y\mod c
```

[image]

and not in the way you are using them.

You probably want a new operator like this:

```
\DeclareMathOperator{\mymod}{mod\,}
```

and then use `Bigl` and `Bigr` or similar to have larger parenthesis:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\DeclareMathOperator{\mymod}{mod\,}

\begin{document}
\[
\Bigl(\mymod\text{THING}\Bigr)
\]
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The command `\mod` introduces some hard coded kerning which you see here. You can just define a new command with the kerning you like. However, `\pmod` keeps this kerning in front of the parentheses. If you want to stick to that, you should do the second approach.

Personally, I do not like to use `\left(\right)` as it makes more harm then help. Therefore, I would define some simpler `\mod`-command for my uses and use the best matching brackets manually.

```
% arara: lualatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{lua-visual-debug}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\myMod}[1]{\allowbreak \if@display \mkern 18mu \else \mkern 0mu\fi {\operator@font mod}\,\,#1} % 0mu was 12mu for the math mode in the orignial defintion
\newcommand{\myPMod}[1]{\allowbreak \if@display \mkern 18mu\else \mkern 8mu\fi \left({{\operator@font mod}\mkern 6mu #1}\right)} % replaced () by \left(\right) in respect to the original definiont
\makeatother    

\begin{document}
% The original \mod 
$\mod{Thing}$

% \mod redefined in order to kick out the math style kerning
$\left(\myMod{Thing}\right)$

% The original \pmod
$\pmod{Thing}$

% \pmod redefined with \left(\right) instead of normal parantheses
$\myPMod{Thing_{g_{g_g}}}$
\end{document}
```

[image]